# Read after symbol

Tags: python-3.x, file-io

Assuming a text file which contains "i = 1", I would like to read "1" and assign it to some variable. So how could I ignore until equal sign and then retrieve the number?

Answer (score 0):

If the text file is formatted like a python file, you can use `exec("file contents")` or even `import` the file. Most people frown upon `exec()` because of its vulnerability: you don't know what code you're running unless you wrote it yourself.

If you're the one that's *putting* the variables into the file, then I would highly suggest looking into `pickle`. It allows you to take python objects and '`dump`' them into a file for later retrieval - and you can make an object with attributes like `self.i = 1` and it will be preserved across runs.

To answer your question directly:

```
#assuming only variables formatted as "variable = value" in file
#assuming only one variable per line
variables = { }
with open("my_variables.txt", "r") as f:
    #iterates through each line
    for line in f:
        #for each line, splits it at the '=' into two parts
        # and gets first half (before the '=') and strips it of any spaces
        # before or after it the variable, then stores it as 'name'
        name = line.split("=")[0].strip()
        #gets second half and stores it as 'value' the same way
        value = line.split("=")[1].strip()
        #if the values are always integers you can convert them
        # from strings to integers:
        value = int(value)
        #stores both variable name and value into the 'variables' dictionary
        variables[name] = value
print(variables) # prints { 'i' : '1' }
```